# addFieldToFilter not working properly

Tags: magento2, collection, filter

When I try to add a field to filter on my magento 2.2.4 quote collection, the quote are not arranged in the right order.

```
$customerId  = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
            echo $customerId; // 2
            $collection = $this->collection->create();
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', customerId);
```

This code reverses my last two ids (121 is after 120).

But this :

```
        $customerId  = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
        echo $customerId;
        $collection = $this->collection->create();
        echo "<pre>".print_r($collection->getData(), true)."</pre>";
```

Is giving me the right order. But i need to filter `$collection` by `customer_id`. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a sort order to the collection (before it's loaded):

```
$field = 'customer_id';
$collection->addOrder(
    $field,
    'DESC' // 'ASC'
);
```

Comment: Yes, I found the solution exactly at the same time you said yours :)